# facebook comments callback function

Tags: facebook, callback, comments

I'm trying to fire an event when you log in to comment, but for some reason the event doesn't fire. Here's my code:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=158693604164389&amp;xfbml=1"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript">

         window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
             FB.init({ appId: '158693604164389', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

             FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {

                 document.getElementById('newsletter-placeholder').style.display = "block";
             });

         };
</script>
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Mauro

Comment: This can happen if your facebook app settings are incorrect. Have you set your site url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you mean, when the user logs-in when trying to use the [**comments plugin**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/)?
If this is what you mean, then no you **can't** capture this event!

> auth.login -- fired when the user logs
>   in

This is fired when the user logs in (connects) to **your** application!